# Parsing XML into NSManagedObjects using categories and what to do with properties in categories?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, properties, nsxmlparser

Based on the excellent example "Parsing XML with NSXMLParser" in the book "The Big Nerd Ranch Guide" (3rd ed.), I haved added categories to my `NSManagedObjects` for which I want to add XML parsing. These categories provide only parsing functionality.

This is how I have implemented these categories:
.h:

```
#import "IBCompany.h"
@interface IBCompany (Xml) <NSXMLParserDelegate>

- (void)parseXmlString:(NSString*)xmlStr withCompletion:(void(^)(NSError *error))completionBlock;

@end
```

.m:

```
@implementation IBCompany (Xml) 

- (void)parseXmlString:(NSString*)xmlStr withCompletion:(void(^)(NSError *error))completionBlock;
{
    NSData *xmlData = [xmlStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithData:xmlData];
    parser.delegate = self;

    [parser parse];

    xmlData = nil;

    NSError *error;
    completionBlock(error);
    }


- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Issue"]) {
                IBIssue *issue = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"IBIssue" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
                issue.company = self;          
                issue.parentParserDelegate = self;
                parser.delegate = issue;
}
```

As you can see in this code snippet, I switch the parser delegate to other subclasses / XML child elements to have them further process the next XML elements, which belong to them until the end of the XML element is reached and the delegate is set back to the parent.

This is why I need to store the parent delegate in the child. However, ivars and properties are not allowed in categories.

I came up with this solution which seems to circumvent this problem:

Child element, h:

```
#import "IBIssue.h"

@interface IBIssue (Xml) <NSXMLParserDelegate>
@property id parentParserDelegate;
@end


#import "IBIssue+Xml.h"

@implementation IBIssue (Xml)

NSMutableString *currentString;
NSString *currentXmlDocument;

id _parentParserDelegate;

- (id)parentParserDelegate
{
    return _parentParserDelegate;
}

- (void)setParentParserDelegate:(id)parentParserDelegate;
{
    _parentParserDelegate = parentParserDelegate;
}

- (NSDateFormatter*)dateFormatter
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    [dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyy-MM-dd"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT: 0]];
    return dateFormatter;
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"IssueID"]) {
        currentString = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];

        if      ([attributeDict[@"Type"] isEqualToString:@"Ticker"])        self.ticker = currentString;
        else if ([attributeDict[@"Type"] isEqualToString:@"Name"])          self.issueName = currentString;
        else if ([attributeDict[@"Type"] isEqualToString:@"CUSIP"])         self.cusip = currentString;
        else if ([attributeDict[@"Type"] isEqualToString:@"ISIN"])          self.isin = currentString;
        else if ([attributeDict[@"Type"] isEqualToString:@"RIC"])           self.ric = currentString;
        else if ([attributeDict[@"Type"] isEqualToString:@"SEDOL"])         self.sedol = currentString;
        else if ([attributeDict[@"Type"] isEqualToString:@"DisplayRIC"])    self.displayRic = currentString;
        else if ([attributeDict[@"Type"] isEqualToString:@"InstrumentPI"]) ; //
        else if ([attributeDict[@"Type"] isEqualToString:@"QuotePI"])      ; //

    } else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Exchange"]) {
        currentString = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];

        self.exchangeCode = attributeDict[@"Code"];
        self.exchangeCountry = attributeDict[@"Country"];
        self.exchange = currentString;
    } else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"MostRecentSplit"]) {
        currentString = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];

        self.mostRecentSplitDate = [self.dateFormatter dateFromString:attributeDict[@"Date"]];
        // self.mostRecentSplit = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: currentString.floatValue];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    // NSLog(@"appendString: %@", string);
    [currentString appendString:string];
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Issue"]) {
        parser.delegate = self.parentParserDelegate;
    } else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"MostRecentSplit"]) {
        self.mostRecentSplit = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: currentString.floatValue];
    }

    currentString = nil;
}

@end
```

I save the delegate to the parent in a variable `_parentDelegate` which is declared outside the ivar declaration block and does not seem to be a real ivar.

This code works well in my tests and I wonder if I missed something which will turn out to become a problem later in the development process or if this design is ok.

What are your thoughts on that?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this. But I'm wondering why you're using a category for this? Why not subclass NSManagedObject if you need additional variables?

Comment: I was inspired by the Stanford lecture on iPhone Development [Core Data and categories, slide 49](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/system/files/lectures/Lecture%2013_2.pdf). Would you rather recommend subclassing the auto-generated subclass `NSManagedObject IBCompany`?

Comment: I completely forgot about this question, sorry. No, I'd suggest you make a new class, XMLManagedObject for example, which is a direct subclass of NSManagedObject. There you can declare the NSXMLParser, handle the basics of parsing, the delegate... Then after you autogenerate your CoreData object classes like IBCompany, you change its subclass to your own class and override the methods where you do parsing specific for that type of object. This seems to me like a much cleaner solution, especially since you seem to want this parsing functionality on multiple types of objects.

Comment: Came across this question while searching for a similar answer. I've solved it by adding `@property (nonatomic, weak) id parentParserDelegate;
` to the interface of the category (in the header file). And now I can just regenerate my NSManagedObject subclasses in Xcode, and leave the parsing code (and other code in the categories) untouched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how the compiler will treat that variable. Could it be allocated so that only one variable is shared by all objects of this type? If your XML is parsed such that more than one IBCompany exists at a point in time it could cause a problem. I'd write a test that allocated two IBCompany objects, cause them both to write different values to _parentDelegate, then assert the values are different.

Or ignore the issue if there is no possibility that two IBCompany objects are parsed in parallel. You'd have to ensure that the XML can't have an IBCompany inside another IBCompany, multiple parts of the XML will not be processed in parallel, and that multiple XML documents will not be processed in parallel.

I don't see the need for a category. Categories are useful when you shouldn't write a subclass to an existing class, such as adding functionality to classes in the Cocoa framework. You are writing a custom subclass, so why not add the ivar to your subclass? You can have additional ivars in managed objects that are not saved in the Core Data backing stores. At most I'd just use an extension to segregate XML parsing code from the rest of the managed object.

Comment: In addition to `IBCompany` there are `IBIssue` and other objects which use the `_parentDelegate` variable and which are called from `IBCompany`. Each of these classes has its own variable `_parentDelegate`, but all are named the same. I have not encountered any problems so far. Is there a better way to parse XML documents into Core Data than mine?

Comment: The _parentDelegate variables in the IBIssue and the other objects are declared independently, so would not overlap. But objects of the same type could overlap if only one variable per implementation file is allocated by the compiler. I don't know if that happens, but I would test for it if I was trying to use this code.

Comment: I want to leave the auto-generated NSManagedObject subclass for IBCompany and the other objects unchanged, because I change the model quite often and would risk overwriting my code if I put it in the same subclass file. Thats why I wanted to have my code (XML parsing and other stuff) separated from these auto-generated files.

Comment: With minor changes, it's easier for me to just add or subtract properties and stock accessors by hand than to maintain separate category files. Also, if I do accidentally or deliberately (for extensive changes) overwrite my files I can always use version control to merge my changes with the newly generated code.